# Thread with Apartment State set to STA has issues sending many queries to postgres database

Tags: c#, multithreading, odbc, postgresql-9.3

I recently solved an issue where my program was crashing while using a BackgroundWorker.

I do not fully understand why there was a problem in the first place. When the thread has it's apartment state set to STA the Process memory increases until the program throws the exception "Unable to allocate environment handle", at first I thought it was an issue with the Database not being able to process the queries quickly enough. The bottom chart on the picture below shows the program running with the thread set to STA. You can see a steady increase in usage until it drops off almost completely. That is when the exception is thrown.

When the thread is running with the ApartmentState set to MTA, the top chart shows it behaving as expected, there is a increase in usage, then it starts a pattern of using and free the memory.

TLDR:
Why does a thread using the Apartment state STA have an issue.

Below I have included some relevant code.

```
BackgroundWorker myWorkerBee;
List<Customers> AllCustomers
private void btnStartConversion_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myWorkerBee = new Thread(myWorkerBee_DoWork);
    myWorkerBee.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    myWorkerBee.Start();
{
private void myWorkerBee_DoWork()
{
    GetOldData(); //Creates Customer object and fills AllCustomers list
    AddCustomers();
}
```

There is no issue with the program if it doesn't use the AddNewCustomerConvert(); Method.

```
private void AddCustomers()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < AllCustomers.Count; i++)
    {
        AllCustomers[i].AddNewCustomerConvert();
    }
}
```

This method exclusively calls the RawQuery(); Method, or methods that only call the RawQuery(); method

```
//REFERENCED PROGRAM

AddNewCustomerConvert()
{
    //40 or so insert statements.
    databaseConnection.RawQuery("//INSERT STATEMENT");
}
```

Sends Queries to the database

```
//REFERENCE DLL
public OdbcDataReader RawQuery(string query_to_perform)
{
    // This method executes a query in the specific database that you 
    // are connected to.
    System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand command = null;

   // holds the query sent to the database
    System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader result_reader = null;

   // The query is put into an OdbcCommand object and sent to the database. The
   // return result will then be given back to the caller.
   try
   {
        if (loggingEnabled)
        {
            myLog = File.AppendText(loggingFileName);
            myLog.WriteLine(query_to_perform);
            myLog.Close();
            myLog.Dispose();
        }
        command = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand(query_to_perform, this.database_connection);
        result_reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        this.successful_query = true;
        this.error_message = "";
    }
    catch (System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException ex)
    {
        this.successful_query = false;
        this.error_message = ex.Message;
        //destroy the connection on a failure
        database_connection = new OdbcConnection();
        throw;
    }
    return result_reader;
}
```

[image: Top: STA Apartment State Bottom: MTA Apartment State]

Comment: First off, you are not using `BackgroundWorker` but plain `Thread`. Second, it's not quite clear why you return `OdbcDataReader` objects. Finally, commands and data readers are disposable resources, you should call `Dispose` when you are done with them. So far I see no relationship to thread apartment state.

Comment: The only difference between the two runs is the apartment state, and it consistently runs this way. It may be a red herring because I'm not sure why it would make a difference. Also calling dispose did not make a difference as far as the program crashing "in" STA